# Prove the sum equation

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Prove the following relation
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{k=1}^{N}\cos^2\big(\frac{k\pi}{N+1}\big) = N-1.
\end{equation}
where $N$ is even. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried grabbing pencil and paper, and looking up trigonometric identities?

Comment: A simple way is to just go into the complex representation of the cosine.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use complex representation, but didn't work out! And there's no such identities in the table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$ S=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^N\left(e^{i\frac{k\pi}{N+1}}+e^{-i\frac{k\pi}{N+1}}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^N\left(e^{2i\frac{k\pi}{N+1}}+e^{-2i\frac{k\pi}{N+1}}+2\right)$$

Can you evaluate this using geometric series?

Comment: They'll prefer to wait until it works out.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You didn't provide a copy-paste-ready answer. But that's what "do my homework" is about.

Comment: I'm working on it!

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Comment: Why did you edit your question? It is good to provide motivation for the question

Comment: Because no one is interested in my motivation!

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos^2 x=\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}\Rightarrow2\sum_{k=1}^N\cos^2\frac{k\pi}{N+1}
=N+\sum_{k=1}^N\cos\frac{2k\pi}{N+1}=N-1,$$

the last equality following from:
$$\sum_{k=0}^N e^{\frac{2\pi k}{N+1}}=0\Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^N\cos{\frac{2\pi k}{N+1}}=0\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^N\cos{\frac{2\pi k}{N+1}}=-1.$$

The first expression is zero as it is sum of all roots of the equation $z^{N+1}=1$.

Comment: Why is the second sum zero?

Comment: The corresponding explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Use power reduce on $2\cos^2 (\pi k / (N+1)) = 1 + \cos (2 \pi k / (N+1))$. Then, it is straightforward to see
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \cos ( 2 \pi k /(N+1)) = -1$$
Whence
$$2 \sum_{k=1}^N \cos^2 (\pi k /(N+1)) = -1 + \sum_{k=1}^N 1 = N-1$$

Comment: I think your answer would be $N$ if the sum of cos is zero!

Comment: Corrected. The sum is $-1$ when the index $k$ starts at $1$, and is $0$ is $k$ started at $0$.

Comment: Where does this sum relation come from?

Comment: The sum in question is precisely the real part of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^N e^{2k \pi / (N+1)}$, then use standard formulas for geometric sums. You'll see that $\sin (k \pi)$ appears in the numerator, hence the $0$.